# c# linq: getting a list of results filtered by values in a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've got the following Statements below (a bit abreviated as I neeed to Change names for posting them here). In essence I have a specific userid and want to filter which Folders have been created that are not created by this user but have one of his Folders as a parent).

Edit:
The code so far (Directory in the database contains int DirectoryId, int ParentDir, String UserId, String Path)
Here the dfinition of Directory

```
public partial class Directory
{
public int DirectoryId { get; set }
public Nullable<int>ParentDir {get; set;}
public string UserId { get; set; }
public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Here the code:

```
 public static List<Directory> GetAllNonUserDirs(string userId)
        {
            MYEntities entity = new MYEntities();
            List<int> DirectoriesOfUser = (from i in entity.Directory
                                                 where (i.UserId == userId)
                                                 select i.DirectoryId).ToList();
            return (from i in entity.Directory where (i.UserId != userId && i.ParentDir.HasValue 
             && DirectoriesOfUser.Contains(i.ParentDir.Value)) select i);
        }
```

Now the Problem is the where sas error "cannot implicitely convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<....> to System.Collecitions.Generic.List<....>.

My question here is how can I solve this Problem (it is caused by the contains part that I made sure of already), or is there an easier way to do the linq Statement?

Note: Writeerrors can have happened as I didnt copy the code but instead rewrote it for here.

Comment: you are just selecting `i.DirectoryId` then how can you check `allDirUser.Contains(i.ParentDir.Value)`

Comment: what do you mean there? I select i.DirectoryId to fill alldirusers with a list of integers and then I try to see with the contains if the parentdir from the second Statement is one of the previously selected ids (thus if it is within the list of integers got in the other Statement) 
Edit: AllDirsUser is the previously fille dlist (AllDirUser was a typing error)

Comment: Please copy and paste your code as this one have many other errors and cannot be diagnosed for the specified error. your parameter type of `userId` is string and `MyDirectory` has `userId` as `int?` as an example.

Comment: @Uriil, there are other formatting issues which you ignored in your edit. Make editing cover as much issues as possible. Don't do minor edits for the sake of editing.

Comment: copied the code and renamed the names so that it is easier to read (no clue why I didnt notice the many typos at first oO)

Comment: I think you should provide directory definition as well

Comment: tnx added it. (the defintion of the properties)

Comment: Also, iy's really confusing when you're giving your entities collection of `MYEntities` type a name of `entity`. It just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ToList()` after the `LINQ` you are returning. Like as follows:

```
 public static List<Directory> GetAllNonUserDirs(string userId)
        {
            MYEntities entity = new MYEntities();
            List<int> DirectoriesOfUser = (from i in entity.Directory
                                                 where (i.UserId == userId)
                                                 select i.DirectoryId).ToList();
            return (from i in entity.Directory where (i.UserId != userId && i.ParentDir.HasValue 
             && DirectoriesOfUser.Contains(i.ParentDir.Value)) select i).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Tnx that was it. would be really interesting wth the red line was under the where there (and did only Show up when I used the contains part but the tolist worked so tnx^^)

Comment: using `ToList` is pointless and bad practice when you could just change the type of the variable, as I explain in my answer.

Comment: @jwg: This is not about the `Contains` method. Error is because `GetAllNonUserDirs()` method returns `List<Directory>` so we will have to return the same type. If we don't use `ToList()`, it returns `IEnumberable<Directory>` which is not correct type and hence it is giving an error. I don't know if [Thomas E](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1381478/thomas-e) has choosen the return type as `List<Directory>` for some specific reason, but ya for sure if there is no specific reason he can change the return type to `IEnumberable<Directory>` and in that case `ToList()` won't be required.

Comment: You are right, I confused the first use of `ToList` with the second.